# Stop code in variable?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

Is it possible to stop or abort a fortran program with an error code/message in a variable? It seems it's not possible with the intrinsic `STOP`:

```
integer :: status = 1
character(len=3) :: err_msg = "err"

stop status  
stop err_msg
```

Both `stop` calls throw syntax errors on compilation. Am I missing something, or do I have to call `stop 1` directly, for example? Or write my own wrapper?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Up to Fortran 2003 the stop code can be either a *scalar-char-constant* or a sequence of up to 5 digits.  A *scalar-char-constant* means what others might call a string, eg your `"err"` but not your `err_msg`.

In Fortran 2008 the stop code can be an expression which returns either a *scalar-default-char-constant-expr* or a *scalar-int-constant-expr*.  If you had a Fortran 2008 compliant compiler then you could use a parameter (*eg* something declared as `character(len=3), parameter :: err_msg = "err"`) as a stop code

Of course, the state of implementation of features introduced in the 2003 and 2008 standards varies from compiler to compiler and version to version.  It looks as if your compiler version doesn't go beyond the Fortran 2003 standard.

And what your operating system does with the stop code is another matter.

Comment: Ah, I'd missed that it was only Fortran 2008 which could use expressions. It seems the latest gfortran supports stop code expressions, but not my version. Bit of a pain.

Comment: @IanH, writing below, has corrected an inaccuracy in an earlier version of this answer which I have now edited. Thanks Ian.

Answer (score 6):

Beyond requiring F2008 - no - not in a *variable*.  In F2008 the stop code must be an integer or character *constant expression*.  Variables are not constants - an expression that relies on the value of a variable is not a constant expression.

If you added the parameter attribute to the declarations of `status` and `err_msg` then they would be [named] constants, and could be used as a primary in the constant expression for a stop or error stop statement.

Comment: That's a bit of a bugger. I guess I'll just have to use `select case` or somesuch.

Comment: I agree.  It is a silly restriction in the language this day and age.  For integer stop codes select case is exactly what I use.

Comment: IanH, (Fortran n00b here) to be explicit, by *constant expression* you mean `CHARACTER, PARAMETER :: err_msg = "err"` would work, yes?

Comment: @Alexis It would work with a compiler that supported this Fortran 2008 feature.  `err_msg` in your comment is declared as a named constant, named constants may appear in constant expressions.

Answer (score 2):

The current standards make no allowances for variables in stop codes. However, they have become more and more flexible as High Performance Mark already stated.

In the upcoming Fortran 2015 standard ([working document from 2016/05/01](http://j3-fortran.org/doc/year/16/16-007r1.pdf), section 8.4) the stop code can be either a *scalar-default-char-expr* or a *scalar-int-expr*. So your code will work with a compliant compiler.

This feature of Fortran 2015 was [added](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-7/changes.html) in version 7 of GCC.